# How can I read from a .txt file to determine the size of a 2-D array?

Tags: c++, recursion, text-files, dynamic-arrays, flood-fill

I am working on a flood-fill recursion assignment where I have to read an ASCII art text file and fill it in. The assignment can be found here: https://faculty.utrgv.edu/robert.schweller/CS2380/homework/hw10.pdf

```
Recursion() //construcor
{
    column = -1;
    row = -1;
    grid = new char*[size of art row];
    for(int i = 0; i < size of art; i++)
    {
        board[row] = new char[size of art column]
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if determining the size of the array should be in the constructor or not. I need to know the size of the array in order to know where the user wants to fill the art file in. Also, here is all of the code for a better context. https://pastebin.com/TSYH26Ci

Comment: I'd suggest you start by reading documentation related to reading files: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream (there's an example at the bottom). Edit this question when you have a specific issue.

Comment: The size of the art is the number of lines by the largest number of characters in a row.  You can know those numbers until you read the file.  I would suggest reading the file into a `vector` of `string`.  The `size` of the `vector` is the row count.  The max `length` of the `string`s is the column count.  You can then convert the `string`s into an array of `char` if that's how you want to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

I would handle your file as binary. I do not know which **OS,API** you are using so I will answer just in generic way...

1. **get file size `siz`**

   usually seeking to `0` bytes from end of file will give you the file size.
2. **allocate 1D array `dat` to store your entire file**

   ```
   dat = new BYTE[siz];
   ```
3. **load your file into memory (1D array)**

   do not forget to use binary access as some ASCII arts could use control codes (**ASCII** below 32) which could be corrupted by text file access.
4. **scan for end of line**

   so scan your array from 0 and stop when you find **ASCII** codes `13` or `10`. Its position will give you the `x` resolution of your **ASCII art**

   ```
   int xs;
   for (xs=0;xs<siz;xs++)
    if ((dat[xs]==10)||(dat[xs]==13))
     break;
   ```

   now `xs` should be holding your `x` resolution.
5. **compute y resolution `ys`**

   the safest way is to count the number of end of lines (13 or 10). In such case you can even store the line start addresses to some pointer array `BYTE **pixel=new (BYTE*)[ys];` which will enable you simple 2D access `pixel[y][x]`. If your **ASCII** art is aligned and have constant size per each line than you can compute `ys` from size..

   ```
   ys = siz/(xs+eol_size)
   ```

   where `eol_size` is 1 or 2 depending on the used line ending: `((10),(13),(13,10) or (10,13))` so:

   ```
   eol_size=1;
   if (xs<siz)
    if ((dat[xs+1]==10)||(dat[xs+1]==13))
     eol_size=2;
   ```

As we do not have access to any input file we can only guess... If you need to generate one see:

- [C++ Image to ASCII art conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32987103/2521214)

Here example of binary file access in **VCL** (bullets **#1,#2,#3**):

- [Convert the Linux open, read, write, close functions to work on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49005275/2521214)