# only read last line of text file (C++ Builder)

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder

Is there an efficient way to read the last line of a text file?  Right now i'm simply reading each line with code like below.  Then S holds the last line read.  Is there a good way to grab that last line without looping through entire text file?

```
TStreamReader* Reader;
Reader = new TStreamReader(myfile);
while (!Reader->EndOfStream) 
{
 String S = Reader->ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Read the file backwards instead of forwards. Read a buffer from the end of the file. Scan the buffer for a line break. If not found, rewind and read the next higher buffer. Scan it. Repeat as needed until a line break is found or the front of the file is reached. If needed, the buffer reading can be optimized using a memory-mapped file view.

Comment: I converted my comment into answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly as  Remy Lebeau commented:

1. **Use file access functions `FileOpen,FileSeek,FileRead`**

   look here for example of usage:

   - [Convert the Linux open, read, write, close functions to work on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49005275/2521214)
2. **load your file by chunks from end into memory**

   so make a static buffer and load file into it from end by chunks ...
3. **stop on `eol` (end of line) usually `CR,LF`**

   just scan for `13,10` ASCII codes or their combinations from end of chunk. Beware some files have last line also terminated so you should skip that the first time ...

   known `eol`s are:

   ```
   13
   10
   13,10
   10,13
   ```
4. **construct line**

   if no `eol` found add whole chunk to string, if found add just the part after it ...

Here small example:

```cpp
int hnd,siz,i,n;
const int bufsz=256;                // buffer size
char buf[bufsz+1];
AnsiString lin;                     // last line output
buf[bufsz]=0;                       // string terminator
hnd=FileOpen("in.txt",fmOpenRead);  // open file
siz=FileSeek(hnd,0,2);              // obtain size and point to its end
for (i=-1,lin="";siz;)
    {
    n=bufsz;                        // n = chunk size to load
    if (n>siz) n=siz; siz-=n;
    FileSeek(hnd,siz,0);            // point to its location (from start)
    FileRead(hnd,buf,n);            // load it to buf[]
    if (i<0)                        // first time pass (skip last eol)
        {
        i=n-1; if (i>0) if ((buf[i]==10)||(buf[i]==13)) n--;
        i--;   if (i>0) if ((buf[i]==10)||(buf[i]==13)) if (buf[i]!=buf[i+1]) n--;
        }
    for (i=n-1;i>=0;i--)            // scan for eol (CR,LF)
     if ((buf[i]==10)||(buf[i]==13))
      { siz=0; break; } i++;        // i points to start of line and siz is zero so no chunks are readed after...
    lin=AnsiString(buf+i)+lin;      // add new chunk to line
    }
FileClose(hnd);                     // close file
// here lin is your last line
```